# Macro para unir duas colunas Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Tenho uma dúvida a respeito do Excel.
Eu tenho duas colunas, gostaria de um macro que ao ser utilizado, transforma todas as linhas dessas duas colunas em linhas de apenas uma coluna.
Sei que posso usar o comando concatenar, mas só sei para fazer em uma linha por vez, meu documento é enorme e torna-se inviável fazer manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, segue o código. Basta selecionar a primeira linha das colunas que quer concatenar. Executa somente com duas colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Option Explicit

Sub concatena_colunas()
    Dim coluna_01 As Long
    Dim coluna_02 As Long
    Dim linha As Long

    On Error GoTo sair:
    'Armazena e coloca em ordem crescente
    coluna_01 = Selection.Areas(1).Column
    If Selection.Areas(2).Column < coluna_01 Then
        coluna_02 = Selection.Areas(1).Column
        coluna_01 = Selection.Areas(2).Column
    Else
        coluna_02 = Selection.Areas(2).Column
    End If

    linha = ActiveCell.Row

    Do
        Cells(linha, coluna_01).Value = Cells(linha, coluna_01).Value & " " & Cells(linha, coluna_02).Text
        linha = linha + 1
    Loop While Cells(linha, coluna_01).Value <> Empty

    coluna_01 = 0
    coluna_02 = 0
    linha = 0
sair:
End Sub
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou o código para mim, modifiquei os valores ali no final do coluna_01 e coluna_02 e linha para as que eu utilizo, mas nada aconteceu. Devo mudar mais algo?

Comment: Não precisa altear o código, basta selecionar a primeira linha de cada coluna que você quer concatenar. Editei a resposta acrescentando uma figura.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui fazer funcionar, mas infelizmente estou tentando unir duas colunas, uma de data e outra de hora, a data é copiada sem problema, mas a hora fica toda desconfigurada, mesmo mudando o tipo de coluna para data+hora. Tem alguma dica pra resolver isso?

Comment: Alterei o código, veja se funciona, aqui funcionou.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado por sua ajuda !